# Ecllipse handler does not fire after installtion

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This problem is really becoming frustrating for me. I have this plugin which has a command, which works perfectly during runtime. When I click on the command during runtime, it does what it is expected to do (create a .cfg file from a .c file). After installation, I am encountering two issues:

1. The handler does not fire after I click on the command.
2. Nothing is printed on the console. I have another plugin whose handlers do what is expected of them after installation, but they fail to print any output to the console.

Where am I going wrong? Could someone please help?

Thank you.

Note: When I click on the command, the control actually goes into the handler class. It is just that it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse console shows the output of programs you are testing, it does **not** show the output of any plugins installed in Eclipse.

The output of things like `System.out.print` are discarded unless Eclipse is started with the `-consoleLog` option (and even then the output is not put in the console).

A plugin can use the various console APIs to create a console for output or to access an existing console.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I managed to make a custom console for displaying output of my plugin.